# How to execute command in Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I am working on a PHP Project in Google Cloud.
I am almost done with my project but I have to execute a command using my PHP script in Google Cloud.

**Let suppose I want to view files**

```
<?php exec('ls') ?>
```

Is there is any way to run commands in Google Cloud ??

Comment: Which app engine are you using, Standard or Flexible? If you are using App Engine Standard Environment, you cannot make system call. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime `An App Engine application cannot: make other kinds of system calls.`

Comment: but i am using flex environment still i'm not able to perform system call...or not able to execute any command using php exec function..

Answer (score 2):

According the [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime)

> **Disabled functions**
>
> The following functions are disabled with the disable_functions directive in php.ini:
>
> - exec

the exec is disabled by default if you use gcp provided php runtime, could add a php.ini file to change this behaviour.

> If you need any of the above functions, add a php.ini file in the root
>   of your application and change the disable_functions directive.
>   Alternatively, set whitelist_functions in the runtime_config section
>   in app.yaml to a comma-delimited list of functions to allow.